# Prove that series convergent exactly when another series convergent.

Tags: convergence-divergence

$(a_k)_{k\geq 1} $ is a monotonically decreasing sequence with numbers $ \geq 0$.

Prove: The series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k $ convergent $\Leftrightarrow$ $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^k*a_{2^k}$ convergent.

My toughts were that if the series on the left side is monotonically decreasing and the series is infinite, from a certain point a partial sum would not grow anymore so the row is limited. But i cant express myself in a mathematical way...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: Or search Cauchy Condensation Test here

Comment: Please do not repost a question after deleting a previous version.  You can just edit it.  See [deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311139/prove-convergnce-of-two-series-with-one-of-them-has-a-monotonically-decreasing-s?noredirect=1#comment4755474_2311139)

Answer (score 1):

Sketch (for one direction):

Write (since the terms of the sum are all positive, the sum is absolutely convergent, so we can rearrange the terms):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1}a_k
$$

Since the sum is decreasing, we know that if $k\leq2^{j+1}$, then $a_k>a_{2^{j+1}}$.  Therefore,
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1}a_k\geq
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1}a_{2^{j+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^ja_{2^{j+1}}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{j-1}a_{2^j}.
$$

Now, just multiply the sum by $2$ to get your desired sum.

For the other direction, try a similar trick (bound the sums above by $2^ja_{2^j}$).